# Using a pattern in for loop in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a program that calculates all sorting possibilities of letters and here is the logic of it. You just enter to call the function and there are 2^n (n is the input value) possiblities. If you enter 3, we know that there exists 8 situations and system generates an automatic string by counting the input value, in example: ABC. And sorts like:

```
ABC
ABc
AbC
Abc
aBC
aBc
abC
abc
```

As you can see, by dividing the possiblities to 2 everytime, puts a letter uppercase or lowercase. I couldn't manage with that in my for loop, can you help me? Here is the code:

```
 function f($hyb, $rand=false) {
    $result="";
    $characters=array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    if ($rand) {
        shuffle($characters);
    }
    for ($i=1; $i<=pow(2, $hyb); $i++) {
        $string=implode(array_slice($characters, 0, $hyb));
        if ($i%2==1) {
        }
        else if ($i%2==0) {
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
echo f(2);
```

Should return AB Ab aB ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a function that does what you're looking for.

```
function f($x) {
  $result = array();
  $characters = range("A", "Z");
  $max = pow(2, $x);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    $val = "";
    $bit = pow(2, $x);
    for ($y = 0; $y < $x; $y++) {
      $bit >>= 1;
      $chr = $characters[$y];
      if ($i & $bit) {
        $chr = strtolower($chr);
      }
      $val .= $chr;
    }
    $result[] = $val;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

A couple differences from your function are: the shuffle function is not implemented, and the above function returns an array rather than a string.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for! I completely understand its logic too, thanks!